# WDS (Webpack Dev Server) Disconnected in VUEJS

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I am new in Vue.js. I have a Vuejs template bought from envato and it has uses "webpack". After installing npm using `npm install`the project is running but there is always below error and warning shows in the browser console,

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

Or, `WDS Disconnected`

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: To which IP is the hot update request being sent? Are you using some kind of virtualization (like Vagrant)?

Comment: No sir. The problem was resolved. Actually it was not an error. It was by default from vue-cli. thank u